# Can I use @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigatorImpl instead of @Binds abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm learning dependency injection by the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#0) with the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt)。

The Code A need instance an object `navigator` by dependency injection , so the author use Code B to implement it, you can see it [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#7).

I'm very strange that the class `AppNavigatorImpl` has implemented the class `AppNavigator` by dependency injection in Code C, so I think Code D will work well.

Can I use  `@Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigatorImpl` instead of `@Binds abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator` ?

**Code A**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
   

    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class NavigationModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator
}
```

**Code C**

```
class AppNavigatorImpl  @Inject constructor(private val activity: FragmentActivity) : AppNavigator {

    override fun navigateTo(screen: Screens) {
        val fragment = when (screen) {
            Screens.BUTTONS -> ButtonsFragment()
            Screens.LOGS -> LogsFragment()
        }

        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment::class.java.canonicalName)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

**Code D**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigatorImpl
   

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can.

The question is, whether you actually want to do that.
Usually you want to depend on abstractions, not concretions ([dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).

If you'd injected the `AppNavigatorImpl`, then you depend on concretion instead of it's abstraction `AppNavigator`.

Also, that page in the codelab teaches how to inject an interface (or an abstract class) as those can't have constructor annotated with `@Inject`.

In your codebase, you usually need to decide whether it's necessary to have this abstraction or not.